# Can't explain this SQL query

Tags: sql, ms-access, if-statement

Im sure these kind of questions are frowned upon but I really need some help. For the past 3 hours I have been staring at this SQL query and I just can't explain some of the logic in it. Normally I wouldn't ask but I'm reaching a deadline.

In the WHERE clause you will see an If construction. From what I can see it checks whether or not the Picking date was valid.

However, the way it's phrased it just looks weird, doesnt it always result in a 'Between'? `(If x > y AND x < z then 'Between', else 'Not Between) = 'Between'`.

And on what object does this 'if' result apply too? The way I interpret it the end result becomes `WHERE 'Between' AND 'Between'`, which just doent make sense...

Any help is appreciated (P.S. The query is written for Access)

```
SELECT
  DWH_PickOrderLines_Temp.*,
  IIf(DWH_PickOrderLines_Temp.WayOfTransport IN ("ON", "PD"), "Kitting " & Mid(tbl_District_Activiteit.Activiteit, 8), IIf(DWH_PickOrderLines_Temp.PickMethode IN ("K", "V"), "Picking Bulk", tbl_District_Activiteit.Activiteit)) AS Activiteit,
  IIf(DWH_PickOrderLines_Temp.WayOfTransport IN ("ON", "PD"), "Kitting", tbl_District_Activiteit.[Activiteit groep]) AS [Activiteit groep],
  R14_Distinct_Warehouse_Location.Proces,
  R14_Distinct_Warehouse_Location.Gebouw
FROM DWH_PickOrderLines_Temp
LEFT JOIN R14_Distinct_Warehouse_Location
  ON DWH_PickOrderLines_Temp.PickLocation = R14_Distinct_Warehouse_Location.PickLocation
WHERE (((IIf([DWH_PickOrderLines_Temp].[PickDateTime] >= [R14_Distinct_Warehouse_Location].[tbl_Location_Zone_District.ValidFrom]
AND [DWH_PickOrderLines_Temp].[PickDateTime] < [R14_Distinct_Warehouse_Location].[tbl_Location_Zone_District.ValidTo], "Between", "Not Between")) = "Between")
AND ((IIf([DWH_PickOrderLines_Temp].[PickDateTime] >= [R14_Distinct_Warehouse_Location].[tbl_District_Activiteit.ValidFrom]
AND [DWH_PickOrderLines_Temp].[PickDateTime] < [R14_Distinct_Warehouse_Location].[tbl_District_Activiteit.ValidTo], "Between", "Not Between")) = "Between"));
```

Comment: Are you sure reported the whole query completely? (where are the join for tbl_Location_Zone_District and tbl_District_Activiteit?)

Comment: Jup, this is the whole query. I noticed the missing join aswell.

Comment: and does it works anyway?

Comment: for what I can argue, anyway, you should simplify it :  
`WHERE [DWH_PickOrderLines_Temp].[PickDateTime] >= [R14_Distinct_Warehouse_Location].[tbl_Location_Zone_District.ValidFrom]
AND [DWH_PickOrderLines_Temp].[PickDateTime] < [R14_Distinct_Warehouse_Location].[tbl_Location_Zone_District.ValidTo] 
AND [DWH_PickOrderLines_Temp].[PickDateTime] >= [R14_Distinct_Warehouse_Location].[tbl_District_Activiteit.ValidFrom]
AND [DWH_PickOrderLines_Temp].[PickDateTime] < [R14_Distinct_Warehouse_Location].[tbl_District_Activiteit.ValidTo]`

Comment: Tip of today: Table aliases!

Answer (score 0):

the where never returns a value. and it is duplicated....

```
declare @pickdate int = 1
declare @validForm int = 0

print 'start'
if(((IIf(@pickdate >= @validForm AND @pickdate < @validForm, 'Between', 'Not Between')) = 'Between') 
AND ((IIf(@pickdate >= @validForm AND @pickdate < @validForm, 'Between', 'Not Between')) = 'Between'))
print 'test'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the query miss a part (references to two tables, see my comment above).  Anyway I think you can simplify where condition:

```
WHERE [DWH_PickOrderLines_Temp].[PickDateTime] >= [R14_Distinct_Warehouse_Location].[tbl_Location_Zone_Distric‌​t.ValidFrom] 
       AND [DWH_PickOrderLines_Temp].[PickDateTime] < [R14_Distinct_Warehouse_Location].[tbl_Location_Zone_Distric‌​t.ValidTo] 
  AND [DWH_PickOrderLines_Temp].[PickDateTime] >= [R14_Distinct_Warehouse_Location].[tbl_District_Activiteit.V‌​alidFrom] 
       AND [DWH_PickOrderLines_Temp].[PickDateTime] < [R14_Distinct_Warehouse_Location].[tbl_District_Activiteit.V‌​alidTo]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think **if** statement always results in 'Between'?

Basically, **where** condition boils down to:

```
where
pickDateTime between validFrom1 and validTo1
and
pickDateTime between validFrom2 and validTo2
```